# Other questions worth looking at?

Tags: discussion

I hate to be a killjoy, but we have a scheme and a purpose with the [Money Self-Evaluation](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/534/personal-finance-and-money-self-evaluation-lets-get-critical). That said, I think it's excellent that you're all choosing to take a harder look at your site!

However, that meta post isn't the place for some of that discussion. So I'm opening this meta post for you all to have the "overflow" conversation from there.

The questions that were added to that meta post were:

- [What does it mean to long convexity of options?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15457/what-does-it-mean-to-long-convexity-of-options/15616#15616)
- [Margin when entered into a derivative contract](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15342/margin-when-entered-into-a-derivative-contract/15417#15417)
- [What are the differences among all these different versions of Vivendi?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15060/what-are-the-differences-among-all-these-different-versions-of-vivendi/15420#15420)
- [Quote driven and order driven financial markets](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15597/quote-driven-and-order-driven-financial-markets/15599#15599)
- [Difference between the multiple cash withdrawal options on these ATMs?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15634/difference-between-the-multiple-cash-withdrawal-options-on-these-atms/15635#15635)
- [Can capital loss be applied for tax for non-consecutive years?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15447/can-capital-loss-be-applied-for-tax-for-non-consecutive-years)
- https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/14837/how-do-you-price-an-option

Feel free to discuss / evaluate these questions in *this* post. And, can I just say, I really like that you all chose to take the initiative to evaluate yourselves further. It's a good sign, and we certainly liked seeing it! Keep up the momentum; we think it'll yield good things for Money.SE.

Comment: In addition to commenting please feel free to "Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par."

Answer (score 2):

**Evaluate me:**
[WSJ article about CFDs - am I missing something?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/14896/wsj-article-about-cfds-am-i-missing-something)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: +1 from me. The question was pretty clear, not to localized and sourced why and from where it originated from.

Answer (score 2):

[Margin when entered into a derivative contract](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15342/margin-when-entered-into-a-derivative-contract/15417#15417) was a basic question with a fine (accepted) answer. Was it a point of discussion? One 'close' vote, that was all.

Comment: No, real reason to single out any of those questions, I just took them at random.

Comment: This question is a good one. It is on-topic. The comments including one by @Chris I think, should be convincing. I believe that the single close vote will eventually go away, time out, so to speak, if not augmented by others. At least I hope that is how it will work, as this question, and the answers given, are fine.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Yes I did, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Does it make sense to refinance a 30 year mortgage to 15 years?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15704/does-it-make-sense-to-refinance-a-30-year-mortgage-to-15-years)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Is there enough information in this question to answer? Is it to specific, or because of its higher level of complexity adds value?

Comment: The question content needs rewriting to be clear. The title is very good. But the question is phrased so specifically that it is a jumble to sort out. The answers aren't too easy to follow either, though I blame the question mostly for that (the answers try to answer based on scenarios resulting from missing details in the question. Not much alternative to that). This is such a relevant question, it is a shame for it not to be structured as well as possible. I am certain it will be viewed a lot.

Comment: This question can only be answered with some math. In the absence of details in the question the answers are placeholders, very detailed placeholders, that can be fixed if the OP ever returns. IF they never du you are left with theory about how to decide.

Comment: With the OP not giving the key data needed (the current time left, and potential closing costs) the best I count offer was to lay out a framework for analysis. His mention of the HELOC was another twist that adds to what makes the question tough to get arms around. Feral - a comment there or specific request for clarification, and I'd be happy to update. Twists aside, the question itself is not unusual.

Answer (score -2):

**Evaluate me:** [Valuation, pricing, and analysis of securities](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15680/valuation-pricing-and-analysis-of-securities/15681#15681)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I personally think its a very simple question. Not a big fan.

Comment: This could be a decent question, but would be helped enormously if the OP responded to this question comment http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15680/valuation-pricing-and-analysis-of-securities/15681#comment20787_15680

Comment: @FeralOink He sort of did respond, I guess the best he could. Since it was a book I guess he couldn't provide a link. Perhaps he could have quoted a line from the book where both are mentioned.

Comment: -1 (If I could vote it) because I realized it is a similar scenario to what Joe explained about this->[Meaning of capital market](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/554/other-questions-worth-looking-at/561#561) and I agree. On top of that the title of the question makes it seem as if it would be a completely different and valid question then what it is.

Answer (score -3):

Evaluate : [Meaning of capital market](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15686/meaning-of-capital-market)

My own comment - this question is of a nature, "I read X on Wikipedia, is it right, or can you clarify?" This specific question compares definitions of a term on Wikipedia and Investopedia and invite discussion of the difference. Are they the same? Are they different? etc.

The topic itself doesn't strike me as PF at all. In my opinion, it's economic. I draw the distinction at whether such knowledge would impact a (non-professional) investor. I don't see it here.

Comment: Agreed, this is not a good question. The answers try hard, but are attempting to reconcile two definitions that may be the same, other than vagaries in wording. There is WAY too much verbiage in the question. It would have been better to ask "Is there a difference in the terms capital market and money market?" I agree with JoeT This is not useful for a non-professional investor (or even for all professional investors)! It is closer to economics, or financial market structure, not within scope for this site.

Comment: -1(for the question) Agreed this question isn't really adding valuable content.

Comment: I have learned to avoid questions of this style. A few have turned into gotcha type debates. One memorable one involved back to back questions from the same person asking about two sentences in a single paragraph from Wikipedia. They basically explained each other. It took way to long to convince the OP it was true.

Comment: sounds like a debate I was involved in lol.